# migration existing schema of titan db

Tags: titan

Need help  in migrate existing titan DB instance ,schema with data to another running titan DB instance in another server .
We created Titan DB instance (schema) using 0.5.4 version.
Is there any API provided by titan for migration ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how many edges do you have in your graph?

Comment: graph have around 100 thousand edges .. and we are using berkeley db at both the instances .

Answer (score 1):

There are no push-button migration utilities in the Titan API.  Most of the time, users write migration scripts in groovy to do data migrations.  This might entail use of titan-hadoop in 0.5.4 or [BLVP](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-hadoop-tp3.html) in Titan 1.0.  In your situation, it doesn't sound like you need any of that.  Just copy the data files of berkeleydb from your original server to your new server.

Comment: thanks for insight stephen, In our case  there are already data loaded in new instance  ,In that case  is it possible to update data files simply by copying from one instance to another ?

Comment: no - if you already have data there then you cannot copy the data files.  you will have to write a script to migrate the data to the target database. luckily, your source graph is small so there isn't much operational complexity here.

Comment: agreed ....thanks Stephen ... instead of writing copy scripts in groovy can this be done in java ? , Or If possible can you direct me to any sample code of groovy for copying data

Comment: You can do it with java, sure.  It's just far easier to open the Titan Gremlin Console and execute your script rather than write a whole "java program". There's no sample code - this is trivial.  Just open both graphs, iterate the source graph for its vertices and write them to the target graph.  Keep a Map as a cache of vertices to track the new identifiers they will get when created in the target graph. Then iterate the edges of the source graph and write those to the new graph.  Use the cache to look up the ids of the new vertices. Commit periodically during iteration.

Comment: stephen , as i asked in orginal question ,is there any api provided by titan that can tell the schema (like edge labels , index created .etc  ) of data or we need to manually traverse whole database to find out schema of each element .Actually my concern is when we will have more than millions edge and data is cosntantly being added then how to  identify the data type , index and other schema elements as traverse will   not be cost effective just for getting the schema.

Comment: thanks stephen ,sorry i couldn't notice your response and asked a new question  in last comment .have you encountered any situatuation as i mentioned in previous comment .

Comment: So you don't manually define your schema in your source database and now you want to migrate to a database where the schema is defined? is that right?

Comment: no stephen , at both the instance we are using titan with berkely db only .In source titan with berkely instance we have created many labels and indexes in many property keys with predefined datatype using titan graph api .SO now we are trying to build one UI interface where we can see all property keys with datatype and indexes created on keys .TO accomplish this we are looking some in built API provided by Titan.

Comment: The `TitanManagement` API let's you query the schema.  do you need something beyond that? http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.5.4/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/TitanManagement.html

Comment: yes .. agreed stephen , But i think these api will be traversing through all the vertices and edges of the graph,in our case with around 1 million edges this might impact performance .to mitigate any impact on existing graph processes i am looking for the API which gives the schema related information without traversing whole graph (one way is if titan stores all the schema related data at some place and while querying it directly return that data instead of traversing through whole graph). thanks in advanse for your inputs

Comment: `TitanManagement` doesn't traverse the graph

Comment: You mean below API doesnt traverse the graph ? then this is good news . public Iterable<VertexLabel> getVertexLabels(); and below API needs input of element type and to get element type i definitly have to traverse the graph to get all elements ?? Please advise .It would be great if there are more API that provide indexes , and other schema related details without traversing .
    public Iterable<TitanGraphIndex> getGraphIndexes(final Class<? extends Element> elementType);
  public Iterable<RelationTypeIndex> getRelationIndexes(RelationType type);

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want me to say.  If you want to know what's in your schema, use the 'TitanManagement' API. Please read more carefully, that method is not asking for an `Element`, it's asking for `Class<? extends Element>`....big difference.

Comment: Also it's worth to look at the sources: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/database/management/ManagementSystem.java
The management methods only touch a handful of vertices ("hidden" schema vertices), hence it doesn't make a difference whether you use them on a 100 node graph or on a 1 billion node graph.

Comment: thanks stephenmallette for your excellent support .. although question is still open ... as guided by Daniel i can see in API that getVertexLabels internally using Iterable) query().has(key, Cmp.EQUAL, attribute).vertices() of StandardTItanTx class which looks like querying whole graph .. @DanielKuppitz your point looks interesting but can you please elaborate as from the API i mentioned it doesnt look like same .

Comment: As I've said before, the queries in `TitanManagement` will only touch a handful of "hidden" vertices, that you - as a user - will never see. Don't worry about a full graph scan, this will never happen in the `TitanManagement` API. If you don't trust me, attach a debugger and you'll see :).

Comment: It does issue some graph queries but they are to a tiny metadata section of the database. `TitanManagement` would be unusable for billion edge graphs if it behaved in the manner that you think it does.